# Of all possible combinations of x coin flips, how many combinations have two heads in a row? How many have exactly a head then tails in a row?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have this question for a practice problem set and I am trying to figure out a way to solve this logically. It is simple to solve iteratively through code, but I am having trouble deriving a formula to solve this.

I know that there are $2^x$ possible combinations based on x coin flips, but I can't figure out a method to extract all combinations that contain either an HH or HT.

Any thoughts? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying stars and bars it can be found that:

$$2^x-\sum_{0\leq k\leq\frac12x+\frac12}\binom{x+1-k}k$$combinations will contain substring "HH".

Unfortunately I cannot find a closed form for $\sum_{0\leq k\leq\frac12x+\frac12}\binom{x+1-k}k$ which of course is the number of combinations that do not contain substring "HH".

---

The case of finding the same for substring "HT" is less difficult.

If e.g. $x=4$ then the following $4+1=5$ combinations do not contain substring "HT":

- HHHH
- THHH
- TTHH
- TTTH
- TTTT

If writing from left to right the first "H" has been placed then only other "H"-s can follow.

This gives $$2^x-x-1$$possible combinations that contain substring "HT".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Sorry I am not very familiar with the mathematical notation for HH- would you mind translating to simpler terms or trying with an example for x (4 or 5)? Just so I can conceptually understand

Comment: I use [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) there. For e.g. $x=5$ we get $2^5-\binom60-\binom51-\binom42-\binom33=32-1-5-6-1$. For $x=4$ we get $2^4-\binom50-\binom41-\binom32=16-1-4-3$. As @awkward showed Fibonacci plays a part in this. I did not recognized that pattern.

Answer (score 4):

drhab has already given you good answers to both questions, but here is an alternate approach for the HH case.

Consider the complementary question: How many sequences of $x$ coin flips do *not* contain HH?  Let's say that number is $a_x$.  It's easy to see by trying all the possible cases that $a_1 = 2$ and $a_2 = 3$.  Now suppose $x> 2$, and suppose we have a sequence of $x+1$ flips with no HH.  Consider the final flip in the sequence; it might be either H or T.  If the final flip is a T, then the first $x$ flips can be any sequence not containing HH, which can be done in $a_x$ ways.  If the final flip is H, then the first $x$ flips must end in T, preceded by any $x-1$ flips without an HH, so this can be done in $a_{x-1}$ ways.  Therefore
$$a_{x+1} = a_x + a_{x-1}$$
for $x > 2$.  This is exactly the recurrence defining the [Fibonacci Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), but with the initial conditions shifted by two; so $a_x = F_{x+2}$, where $F_x$ is the x-th Fibonacci number.

The answer to the original problem, how many sequences contain at least one HH, is then
$$2^x - F_{x+2}$$
If you need a quick way to calculate $F_x$, it is known that $F_x$ is the nearest integer to $\phi^x/\sqrt{5}$, where $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: Nice. So Fibonacci turns up as summation of binomial coefficients.